# Which features of android are not supported in web apps/Cordova?

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I want the description of features which can work fine in a native app(android), but not in cordova app as in used with android as a platform. In other words features of android which are not supported in cordova(android) application.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you will find hardly any features, which native app can do and cordova app can't do. As main reason is "Cordova app is a native app", just with a full screen web view rendering HTML content.
For more info check [Cordova site](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/overview/) and [quora thread](https://www.quora.com/What-cant-Apache-Cordova-do).
There are plugins available to access different features.

If you are in conflict which to use read this answer.